# Max-If excel replication in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate the max if function from Excel in R.

```
ksu       price   max
9144037   3.11    3.11
8448749   4.19    5.24
9649391   0       8.39
8448749   4.19    5.24
8448749   4.19    5.24
8448749   4.19    5.24
8448749   4.19    5.24
9649391   8.39    8.39
8448749   5.24    5.24
9144037   1.99    3.11
9144037   1.99    3.11
```

If I were doing it in excel i'd use max(if()). This code is supposed to look at the max price for each ksu, and return the max value on the last column. I've tried this :

```
max(price[ksu == ksu])
```

But it doesn't give me the desired output. It only returns one max value regardless of the ksu.

Comment: For future reference please read the following before submitting any more questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a data.frame called `df` you could easily use the `ave` function to get what you want.  An example:

```
> df <- data.frame(grp = c('a','a','b','b'), vals = 1:4)
> df
  grp vals
1   a    1
2   a    2
3   b    3
4   b    4
> # Returns a vector
> ave(df$vals, df$grp, FUN = max)
[1] 2 2 4 4
> # So we can store it back into the data.frame if we want
> df$max <- ave(df$vals, df$grp, FUN = max)
> df
  grp vals max
1   a    1   2
2   a    2   2
3   b    3   4
4   b    4   4
```

So using your variable names (but still assuming the data.frame is `df`):

```
df$max <- ave(df$price, df$ksu, FUN = max)
```

Comment: Another option is `setDT(df)[,  Max := max(vals), grp]`

Comment: @akrun Right. I was going for a base solution but you can submit a data.table solution if you want.

Comment: You can add it as it is very simple

Comment: Sure it's simple but it's a different approach. No harm in having multiple answers. Honestly the question probably could be closed as a dupe of *something* but I'm too lazy to find the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is in a `data.frame` called `dat`, we can use the **`dplyr`** package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ksu) %>%
  mutate(max = max(price))

       ksu price   max
     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  9144037  3.11  3.11
2  8448749  4.19  5.24
3  9649391  0.00  8.39
...
```